# Sum of difference of squares between each combination of rows of 17,000 by 300 matrix

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, matrix

Ok, so I have a matrix with 17000 rows (examples) and 300 columns (features). I want to compute basically the euclidian distance between each possible combination of rows, so the sum of the squared differences for each possible pair of rows.
Obviously it's a lot and iPython, while not completely crashing my laptop, says "(busy)" for a while and then I can't run anything anymore and it certain seems to have given up, even though I can move my mouse and everything.

Is there any way to make this work? Here's the function I wrote. I used numpy everywhere I could.
What I'm doing is storing the differences in a difference matrix for each possible combination. I'm aware that the lower diagonal part of the matrix = the upper diagonal, but that would only save 1/2 the computation time (better than nothing, but not a game changer, I think).

**EDIT**: I just tried using `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`but it's been running for a good minute now with no end in sight, is there a better way? I should also mention that I have NaN values in there...but that's not a problem for numpy apparently.

```
features = np.array(dataframe)
distances = np.zeros((17000, 17000))


def sum_diff():
    for i in range(17000):
        for j in range(17000):
            diff = np.array(features[i] - features[j])
            diff = np.square(diff)
            sumsquares = np.sum(diff)
            distances[i][j] = sumsquares
```

Comment: @TimPietzcker, hmm I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be 17000 for each loop because I'm doing distance between each combination of rows (pairs) and there's 17k of those. However, I just realized that I have `i` for both loop variables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always divide your computation time by 2, noticing that d(i, i) = 0 and d(i, j) = d(j, i).

But have you had a look at `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances()` (in v 0.18, see [the doc here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html)) ?

You would use it as:

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 3]])
pairwise.pairwise_distances(a)
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked way better than scipy's pdist, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The big thing with numpy is to avoid using loops and to let it do its magic with the vectorised operations, so there are a few basic improvements that will save you some computation time:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

#I reduced the problem size to 1000*300 to keep the timing in reasonable range
n=1000
features = np.random.rand(n,300)
distances = np.zeros((n,n))


def sum_diff():
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            diff = np.array(features[i] - features[j])
            diff = np.square(diff)
            sumsquares = np.sum(diff)
            distances[i][j] = sumsquares

#Here I removed the unnecessary copy induced by calling np.array
# -> some improvement
def sum_diff_v0():
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            diff = features[i] - features[j]
            diff = np.square(diff)
            sumsquares = np.sum(diff)
            distances[i][j] = sumsquares

#Collapsing of the statements -> no improvement
def sum_diff_v1():
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            distances[i][j] = np.sum(np.square(features[i] - features[j]))

# Using brodcasting and vetorized operations -> big improvement
def sum_diff_v2():
    for i in range(n):
        distances[i] = np.sum(np.square(features[i] - features),axis=1)

# Computing only half the distance -> 1/2 computation time
def sum_diff_v3():
    for i in range(n):
        distances[i][i+1:] = np.sum(np.square(features[i] - features[i+1:]),axis=1)
    distances[:] = distances + distances.T

print("original :",timeit.timeit(sum_diff, number=10))
print("v0 :",timeit.timeit(sum_diff_v0, number=10))
print("v1 :",timeit.timeit(sum_diff_v1, number=10))
print("v2 :",timeit.timeit(sum_diff_v2, number=10))
print("v3 :",timeit.timeit(sum_diff_v3, number=10))
```

**Edit :** For completeness I also timed Camilleri's solution that is **much faster**:

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise

def Camilleri_solution():
    distances=pairwise.pairwise_distances(features)
```

**Timing results** (in seconds, function run 10 times with 1000*300 input):

```
original : 138.36921879299916
v0 : 111.39915344800102
v1 : 117.7582511530054
v2 : 23.702392491002684
v3 : 9.712442981006461
Camilleri's : 0.6131987979897531
```

So as you can see we can easily gain an order of magnitude by using the proper numpy syntax. Note that with only 1/20th of the data the function run in about one second so I would expect the whole thing to run in the tens of minutes as the scipt runs in N^2.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to type all of this. I wish I could choose your answer because it taught me stuff about numpy I didn't know, but P. Camilleri's answer got this to run really fast, so I have to go with his.

Comment: No problem, that's the right choice. I'll add timing for Camilleri's solution to show how much faster it is.